# How to handle a dynamic collection as stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Java 8 collections provide features to obtain a collection as stream. However once we call stream() method, we get current contents of the collection as stream.
What if my collection grows during stream processing? The operations on the stream might update the collection with more data. Is there a simple & effective way to handle this situation?

( I tried Stream.concat() from within the stream processing operation but I get exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed )

Taking a specific example, suppose I have a concurrent queue of urls.

```
Queue<Url> concurrentUrlQue= initUrlQueue();
```

Now I want to obtain stream of this url queue, and process the URLs one by one. The process involves removing url from queue, reading the web pages pointed by the url, extracting URLs from the page and adding those URLs into the concurrent queue.

```
concurrentUrlQue.stream().forEach((url)->readAndExtractUrls(url, concurrentUrlQue));
```

I want to be able to handle the above dynamically growing queue as a stream. (Further, I want to be able to process this dynamic queue using parallel stream)

Is there a simple way of achieving this using java streams?

Comment: You should consult the [javadoc of `java.util.Spliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html). It's long, but anwsers your question.

Comment: I will go through it, but can you hint me how could spliterator solve the problem that I'm trying to solve?

Comment: So you have a URL that may produce additional URLS that may produce even more, and you want them all in the same collection?  It sounds like you want some sort of recursion that can be ran in parallel.  Spliterator sounds interesting.

Comment: yes, I have a queue, elements from which I process, processed results are added back to the queue so that they are processed further. I handled this and even parallelly without using streams. I want a stream approach for this.

Comment: If you really want to do this with stream, you are just writing a awkward `Spliterator` which is actually just a [`ForkJoinTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html). You should be using that class and its affiliate, [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), instead.

Comment: @Nick Ziebert yes, I'll add all the urls into the same queue for further processing, however also note that I'll removing items from queue when they are picked for processing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write spliterator that blocks on waiting for the new element.

```
class QueueSpliterator<T> extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T> {

  private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;

  public QueueSpliterator(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
    super(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0);
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    try {
      T element = queue.take();
      action.accept(element);
      return true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you create a stream using that spliterator and handle it like an ordinary infinite stream.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);

    new Thread(() -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        try {
          queue.put(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    }).start();


    Spliterator<Integer> queueSpliterator = new QueueSpliterator<>(queue);
    Stream<Integer> stream = StreamSupport.stream(queueSpliterator, false);

    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```